# How to replace the value in same colomn - power bi query editor

Tags: powerbi, duplicates, conditional-formatting

I got bellow query table, now i need one more column that would show all the latest value of unit id which is the true value of the Custom and currentUnit column

[data table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcZ7H.png)

expected result would be in the image
[expected result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mT1ye.png)

Any help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Copy currentUnit to New
2. Replace false with null
3. Transform - Fill up
4. Replace value with null where custom = True
5. Provide sample data in copyable format if you need more detailed instructions